# recursive file search thread

Tags: delphi, recursion, multithreading

i have a routine that searches files:

```
procedure RecSearch(const sPathName, sFile : String; const subDir : Boolean);
var
   sr    : TSearchRec;
   sPath : String;
begin
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   sPath:=IncludeTrailingBackslash(sPathName);
   if FindFirst(sPath + sFile, faAnyFile - faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
   repeat
      lstBox.Items.Add(sPath + sr.Name); // send files into a ListBox
   until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
   FindClose(sr);

   If not subDir then Exit;

   if FindFirst(sPath + '*.*', faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
   repeat
      if ((sr.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)  and (sr.Name<>'.') and (sr.Name<>'..') then
         RecSearch(sPath + sr.Name, sFile, True);
   until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
   FindClose(sr);
end;
```

my problem is that i want to use a thread that does all the work and i can't get it done

i tryed this and it only searches in the current/selected dir, not in subdirs

```
const
  WM_ThreadDoneMsg = WM_User + 8;

type TfrmSearch = class;

CSearchThread = class(TThread)
   private
      OwnerForm      : TfrmSearch;
      cntFFound      : Integer;
      inPath, inFile : String;
      inFileAttr     : Integer;
      inFileSize     : LongInt;
      procedure RecSearch(const sPath, sFile : String; const subDir : Boolean);
      procedure AddFile;
   protected
      procedure Execute; override;
   published
      constructor Create(owner : TfrmSearch);
      destructor  Destroy; override;
end;

TfrmSearch = class(TForm)
...
   edPath: TEdit;
   edSearchFor: TEdit;
   chkSubfolders: TCheckBox;
   lvFiles: TListView;
...
   private
   public
      srcThread : CSearchThread;
      procedure SearchThreadDone(var msg : TMessage); message WM_ThreadDoneMsg;
end;

var
  frmSearch: TfrmSearch;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor CSearchThread.Create(owner : TfrmSearch);
begin
   inherited Create(True);
   OwnerForm:=owner;
   FreeOnTerminate:=True;
   Suspended:=False;
   Priority:=tpHigher;
   cntFFound:=0;
   // clear previous entryes
   ownerForm.lvFiles.Clear;
   ownerForm.StatusBar.Panels[0].Text:='';
end;

destructor CSearchThread.Destroy;
begin
   PostMessage(OwnerForm.Handle, WM_ThreadDoneMsg, Self.ThreadID, 0);
   inherited destroy;
end;

procedure CSearchThread.AddFile;
var
   li    : TListItem;
begin
   li:=OwnerForm.lvFiles.Items.Add;
   li.Caption:=inFile;
   li.SubItems.Add(inPath);
   OwnerForm.StatusBar.Panels[0].Text:=IntToStr(cntFFound)+' files found';
end;

procedure CSearchThread.RecSearch(const sPath, sFile : String; const subDir : Boolean);
var
  sr   : TSearchRec;
  attr : Integer;
begin
   OwnerForm.StatusBar.Panels[1].Text:=IntToStr(1+StrToInt(OwnerForm.StatusBar.Panels[1].Text));
   if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingBackslash(sPath)+sFile, faAnyFile - faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
   repeat
         inPath:=sPath;
         inFile:=sr.Name;
         inFileAttr:=sr.Attr;
         inFileSize:=sr.Size;
         Synchronize(AddFile);
   until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
   FindClose(sr);

   if not subDir then Exit;

   if FindFirst(sPath + '*.*', faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
   repeat
      if ((sr.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)  and (sr.Name<>'.') and (sr.Name<>'..') then
         RecSearch(sPath + sr.Name, sFile, True);
   until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
   FindClose(sr);
end;

procedure CSearchThread.Execute;
begin
   if DirectoryExists(ownerForm.edPath.Text) then
   begin
      RecSearch(ownerForm.edPath.Text, OwnerForm.edSearchFor.Text, OwnerForm.chkSubfolders.Checked);
   end
   else
      ShowMessage('Path not found');
end;

procedure TfrmSearch.SearchThreadDone(var msg : TMessage);
begin
   bbtnPause.Enabled:=False;
end;
```

Comment: Which Delphi Version are you using? I'm asking because Delphi 2010 has the new IOUtils.pas unit which exposes TDirectory, very very useful for File I/O

Comment: "OwnerForm.StatusBar.Panels[].Text :=" - it should be done with Synchronize

Comment: i noticed :), but that is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found what i was looking for @ [pascal newsletter](http://www.latiumsoftware.com/en/pascal/delphi-newsletter.php) #01
i'll look again on my code and search for my error

unit1.dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 468
  Top = 177
  Width = 467
  Height = 354
  Caption = 'File Search'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignSize = (
    459
    320)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 17
    Top = 13
    Width = 55
    Height = 13
    Alignment = taRightJustify
    Caption = 'File &Names:'
    FocusControl = Edit1
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 19
    Top = 42
    Width = 53
    Height = 13
    Alignment = taRightJustify
    Caption = '&Containing:'
    FocusControl = Edit2
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Left = 31
    Top = 72
    Width = 41
    Height = 13
    Alignment = taRightJustify
    Caption = 'In f&older:'
    FocusControl = Edit3
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 376
    Top = 6
    Width = 78
    Height = 24
    Anchors = [akTop, akRight]
    Caption = '&Find'
    Default = True
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 376
    Top = 38
    Width = 78
    Height = 24
    Anchors = [akTop, akRight]
    Cancel = True
    Caption = '&Cancel'
    Enabled = False
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object StatusBar1: TStatusBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 301
    Width = 459
    Height = 19
    Panels = <>
    SimplePanel = True
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 74
    Top = 8
    Width = 291
    Height = 21
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
    TabOrder = 3
    Text = '*.ini'
  end
  object Edit2: TEdit
    Left = 74
    Top = 37
    Width = 291
    Height = 21
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
    TabOrder = 4
    Text = 'General'
  end
  object Edit3: TEdit
    Left = 75
    Top = 67
    Width = 290
    Height = 21
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
    TabOrder = 5
    Text = 'C:\Windows'
  end
  object CheckBox1: TCheckBox
    Left = 76
    Top = 97
    Width = 111
    Height = 13
    Caption = '&Include subfolders'
    TabOrder = 6
  end
  object ListView1: VListView
    Left = 0
    Top = 120
    Width = 459
    Height = 188
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
    Columns = <
      item
        Caption = 'Name'
        Width = 150
      end
      item
        Caption = 'Folder'
        Width = 300
      end>
    TabOrder = 7
    ViewStyle = vsReport
    OnDblClick = ListView1DblClick
    OnMouseDown = ListView1MouseDown
  end
  object Animate1: TAnimate
    Left = 393
    Top = 66
    Width = 48
    Height = 50
    Anchors = [akTop, akRight]
    FileName = 'C:\LatiumSoft\Pascal#001\findfile.avi'
    StopFrame = 23
  end
end
```

unit1.pas:

```
unit Unit1;

    //{$DEFINE Spanish}

    {
    Copyright (c) 2001 Ernesto De Spirito
    Latium Software  http://www.latiumsoftware.com/
    Email: edespirito @ latiumsoftware.com

    To try this example you first have to install the ListViewX component
    and set a correct value for the FileName property of the Animate1
    control (the full path name of an AVI file).

    Para probar este ejemplo primero debe instalar el componente ListViewX y
    establecer un valor correcto para la propiedad FileName del control
    Animate1 (la ruta y nombre completo de un archivo AVI).
    }

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, ComCtrls, StdCtrls, ShellAPI, ListView;

    const
      WM_ThreadDoneMsg = WM_User + 8;

    {$IFDEF Spanish}
      cstrCouldNotExecApp = 'No se pudo ejecutar la aplicaci≤n';
      cstrSearchEnded = 'B·squeda finalizada (%d ficheros encontrados).';
      cstrSearchCancelled =
        'B·squeda cancelada (%d ficheros encontrados).';
      cstrSearching = 'Buscando... (%d ficheros encontrados)';
      cstrEnterFileSpec = 'Especifique el nombre de archivo';
      cstrEnterKeywords = 'Especifique el texto de b·squeda';
      cstrEnterFolder = 'Especifique la carpeta inicial';
    {$ELSE}
      cstrCouldNotExecApp = 'Couldn''t execute the application';
      cstrSearchEnded = 'Search ended (%d files found).';
      cstrSearchCancelled = 'Search cancelled (%d files found).';
      cstrSearching = 'Searching... (%d files found)';
      cstrEnterFileSpec = 'Enter file spec';
      cstrEnterKeywords = 'Enter keywords';
      cstrEnterFolder = 'Enter folder';
    {$ENDIF}

    {$IFDEF WIN32}
      PathSeparator: char = '\';
      DriveSeparator: char = ':';
    {$ELSE}
      PathSeparator: char = '/';
      // DriveSeparator: char = ' ';
    {$ENDIF}


    type
      TForm1 = class;

      TThread1 = class(TThread)
      private
        OwnerForm: TForm1;
        Location: string;
        FileName: string;
        Count: cardinal;
        procedure Initialize;
        procedure AddFileName;
        procedure Finalize;
      protected
        procedure Execute; override;
      published
        constructor Create(Owner: TForm1);
        destructor Destroy; override;
      end;

      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        Button2: TButton;
        StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
        Edit1: TEdit;
        Label1: TLabel;
        Edit2: TEdit;
        Label2: TLabel;
        Edit3: TEdit;
        Label3: TLabel;
        CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
        ListView1: VListView;
        Animate1: TAnimate;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
        procedure ListView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure ListView1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
          Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
      private
        { Private declarations }
        Last: TPoint;
        Thread1: TThread1;
        procedure Thread1Done(var AMessage: TMessage); message WM_ThreadDoneMsg;
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.DFM}

    //---------------------------------------------------------------

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      c: char;
    begin
      if Edit1.Text = '' then begin
        MessageDlg(cstrEnterFileSpec, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
        Edit1.SetFocus;
      end else if Edit2.Text = '' then begin
        MessageDlg(cstrEnterKeywords, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
        Edit2.SetFocus;
      end else if Edit3.Text = '' then begin
        MessageDlg(cstrEnterFolder, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
        Edit3.SetFocus;
      end else begin
        c := Edit3.Text[Length(Edit3.Text)];
        if (c <> PathSeparator) and (c <> DriveSeparator) then
          Edit3.Text := Edit3.Text + PathSeparator;
        Button1.Enabled := False;
        Edit1.Enabled := False;
        Edit2.Enabled := False;
        Edit3.Enabled := False;
        Checkbox1.Enabled := False;
        Button2.Enabled := True;
        Thread1 := TThread1.Create(Self);
    //    Animate1.Active := True;
      end;//if
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Thread1.Terminate;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Thread1Done(var AMessage: TMessage);
    begin
    //  Animate1.Active := False;
      Button1.Enabled := True;
      Edit1.Enabled := True;
      Edit2.Enabled := True;
      Edit3.Enabled := True;
      Checkbox1.Enabled := True;
      Button2.Enabled := False;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    begin
      if Button2.Enabled then begin
        Thread1.Terminate;
        Thread1.WaitFor;
      end; // if
      Action := caFree;
    end;

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    constructor TThread1.Create(Owner: TForm1);
    begin
      inherited Create(True);
      OwnerForm := Owner;
      Priority := tpHigher;
      FreeOnTerminate := True;
      Suspended := False;
    end;

    destructor TThread1.Destroy;
    begin
      PostMessage(OwnerForm.Handle,
        WM_ThreadDoneMsg, Self.ThreadID, 0);
      inherited destroy;
    end;

    procedure TThread1.Execute;
    var
      Content: TStringList;
      Keywords: string;

    procedure ScanFolder(const folder: string);
    var
      SearchRec: TSearchRec;
    begin
      if FindFirst(folder + OwnerForm.Edit1.Text,
          faReadOnly Or faHidden Or faSysFile Or faArchive,
          SearchRec) = 0 then begin
        repeat
          try
            FileName := SearchRec.Name;
            Content.LoadFromFile(folder + FileName);
            if AnsiPos(Keywords, AnsiUpperCase(Content.Text))
                <> 0 then begin
              Inc(Count);
              Location := folder;
              Synchronize(AddFileName);
            end; // if
          except
          end; // try
        until Terminated Or (FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0);
      end; // if
      FindClose(SearchRec);
      if (not Terminated) and OwnerForm.Checkbox1.Checked then begin
        if FindFirst(folder + '*', faReadOnly Or faHidden
            Or faSysFile Or faArchive Or faDirectory,
            SearchRec) = 0 then begin
          repeat
            try
              if ((SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0)
                  and (SearchRec.Name <> '.')
                  and (SearchRec.Name <> '..') then
                ScanFolder(folder + SearchRec.Name + PathSeparator);
            except
            end; // try
          until Terminated Or (FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0);
        end; // if
        FindClose(SearchRec);
      end; // if
    end;

    begin // procedure TThread1.Execute;
      Count := 0;
      Synchronize(Initialize);
      Content := TStringList.Create();
      Keywords := AnsiUpperCase(OwnerForm.Edit2.Text);
      ScanFolder(OwnerForm.Edit3.Text);
      Content.Free;
      Synchronize(Finalize);
    end;

    procedure TThread1.Initialize;
    begin
      OwnerForm.StatusBar1.SimpleText :=
        Format(cstrSearching, [Count]);
      OwnerForm.ListView1.Items.Clear;
    end;

    procedure TThread1.AddFileName;
    var
      ListItem: TListItem;
    begin
      OwnerForm.StatusBar1.SimpleText := Format(cstrSearching, [Count]);
      ListItem := OwnerForm.ListView1.Items.Add();
      ListItem.Caption := FileName;
      ListItem.SubItems.Add(Location);
    end;

    procedure TThread1.Finalize;
    begin
      if Terminated then
        OwnerForm.StatusBar1.SimpleText :=
          Format(cstrSearchCancelled, [Count])
      else
        OwnerForm.StatusBar1.SimpleText :=
          Format(cstrSearchEnded, [Count]);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.ListView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      Col: Integer;
      ListItem: TListItem;
    begin
      ListItem := ListView1.GetItemAtX(Last.X, Last.Y, Col);
      if ListItem <> nil then begin
        if Col = 0 then begin
          if ShellExecute(Self.Handle, nil,
               PChar(ListItem.SubItems.Strings[0] + ListItem.Caption),
               nil, nil, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED) <= 32 then begin
            Application.MessageBox(cstrCouldNotExecApp,
              'Error', MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
          end;//if
        end else if Col = 1 then begin
          if ShellExecute(Self.Handle, 'explore',
              PChar(ListItem.SubItems.Strings[0]),
              nil, nil, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED) <= 32 then begin
            Application.MessageBox(cstrCouldNotExecApp,
              'Error', MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
          end; // if
        end; // if
      end; // if
    end;

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    {$IFDEF Spanish}
      Button1.Caption := '&Buscar';
      Button2.Caption := '&Detener';
      Label1.Caption := 'No&mbre:';
      Label2.Caption := 'Con el &texto:';
      Label3.Caption := 'B&uscar en:';
      CheckBox1.Caption := '&Incluir subcarpetas:';
      ListView1.Columns[0].Caption := 'Nombre';
      ListView1.Columns[1].Caption := 'Ubicaci≤n';
    {$ENDIF}
    end;

    procedure TForm1.ListView1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
      Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    begin
      Last.X := X;
      Last.Y := Y;
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: The code in this newsletter leaves much to be desired. Loren Pechtel highlights some of the shortcomings in his answer, but the biggest blunder is to use `WaitFor` on a self-destroying thread - this is a crash waiting to happen. If you want to see a better example for file scanning in a worker thread, check out the OTL implementation here: http://17slon.com/blogs/gabr/2008/11/background-file-scanning-with.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try [FindFile](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/findfile/) component, which can search for a given path in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

I see two cases of the thread accessing VCL components--a big no-no.  Build up your list of files in a list that's not part of a visual component and is not touched by anything else while the thread is running.

Also, post back a message giving the number of files found, don't update it directly.

Finally, don't update the files found count for every file.  I've seen a program become completely nonresponsive to user input because of such excessive updating.  I'd do something like updating after every directory and every 100 files in a directory or something like that.

Comment: +1, good advice. Even better would be to let the VCL thread decide how often it will update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

In the first procedure, it looks like you add a path separator to the end of sPath:

```
sPath:=IncludeTrailingBackslash(sPathName);
```

Whereas in the second, you only add the separator in the call to FindFirst

```
if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingBackslash(sPath)+sFile, faAnyFile - faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
```

When you later append a path component to sPath, there's thus no separator between the new component and the rest of the path

```
if FindFirst(sPath + '*.*', faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
   ...
      RecSearch(sPath + sr.Name, sFile, True);
```